# create Google Chart through AJAX call with JSON/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, google-visualization

CI'm having an issue creating a chart. I've read number of tutorials and basically wrote a code according to them. However, the problem is that the chart won't be displayed at all.
I want on AJAX call to retrieve data from SQLite3 and then draw a chart based on that data.
It could be Column or Pie chart, doesnt matter.
I'm pretty sure there is some kind of problem with the way I work on JSON, and I would like someone to help me. Thanks!

```
          #test.html
          -------------------------------------------------------------------------
          <html>
          <head>
          <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript">   

           function drawChart() {
                var jsonData = $.ajax({
                url: "test-return.php",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false
           }).responseText;


           document.getElementById('rightDiv').innerHTML = jsonData;

           var jsonData2 = [["FC Internazionale ",24],["AS Roma ",24],["Milan AC ",20],["UC Sampdoria ",19],["US Citt\u00e0 di Palermo",18],["SSC Napoli ",15],["Juventus FC ",16],["Parma FC ",14],["Genoa CFC ",14],["AS Bari ",13],["AC Fiorentina ",13],["SS Lazio ",11],["Calcio Catania ",10],["Cagliari Calcio ",11],["Udinese Calcio ",11],["AC Chievo Verona ",12],["Bologna FC ",10],["Atalanta BC ",9],["AC Siena ",7],["AS Livorno Calcio ",7]];

           var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsonData2,true);

           var options = {
                title: 'table 1'
           };

           var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(
                    document.getElementById('chart_div'));
           chart.draw(data, options);
          }
          google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart'], callback: drawChart});

         </script>
       </head>
       <body>
            <div id="chart_div" style="width: 400px; height: 500px;"></div>

            <div id="rightDiv">query results</div>  
       </body>
       </html>


       #test-return.php
       -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
       <?php
              sqlite code here
              ................
              echo json_encode($row_array);
       ?>

       $row_array output => [["FC Internazionale ",24],["AS Roma ",24],["Milan AC ",20],["UC Sampdoria ",19]......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to match your data format to format expected by your chosen chart type.  As-is, you will have 3 columns of data: one numeric, one string, and one numeric.  The PieChart expects two columns of data: the first should be type "string" and the second should be type "number".  ColumnCharts can have any number of columns: the first can be either type "number", "date", "datetime", "timeofday", or "string", but all of the following columns should be type "number" (usually, that is - there are some exceptions that have to do with using column roles which are outside the scope of what you are doing here).

Looking at your data, I am speculating that the first column (the 1, 2, 3, 4... in your sample data) is a row number and not something you intend to plot.  If this is the case, you need to adjust your server-side code to remove it.  If this is not the case, can you provide information about it so I can help you figure out how to use it?

Also, your data is missing column headers.  As structured, the `arrayToDataTable` method will take the first row of data and use it as the column headers, so you would get three columns with the labels "1", "FC Internazionale ", and "24", which you probably don't want.  Either amend your server-side code to make the first row of data contain column labels, or set the second argument in the `arrayToDataTable` call to `true`.

By using `jsonData = $.ajax(...).responseText;`, you are bypassing the JSON conversion that jQuery does and passing the raw text of the response to `jsonData`.  Since you need a javascript array to use the `arrayToDataTable` method, you need to call `JSON.parse` on `jsonData` to convert it to an array:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(JSON.parse(jsonData), true);
```

Comment: Greetings! thank you for sharing this valuable info with me. i've certainly made necessary adjustments to server side code to remove these unnecessary numbers(1, 2, 3....). Ialso added boolean true just as you suggested, but for some reason it's still wouldnt work. Any ideas? I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Using the code and JSON string you provided, I was able to get the chart to draw: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/LfaUh/.  Open the page in Chrome and check the developer's console (ctrl+shift+j to open in the Windows version).  Are there any errors reported?  If not, navigate to `test-return.php` in your browser and confirm that it is outputting the array correctly.

Comment: Thanks this certainly helped to understand the issue. Error is reported indeed, => "Not an array". But I still have clue why? I went ahead and modified code to see if jsonData var that's calling ajax does hold anything or not? well, it does, since I'm able to print that array into a different div.....just as you see in the code.....any clue what is the problem?

Comment: So, the 'rightDiv' gets the array, that's jsonData actually holds the array, but for some reason when i insert this variable into arrayToDataTable(jsonData, true) it wouldnt do anything.....

Comment: Ahh, I see the problem now.  You set up your AJAX to return the raw text string of JSON, which needs to be converted into a javascript array in order for the `arrayToDataTable` method to work.  Use the `JSON.parse` function to get it running.  See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/LfaUh/2/.  Updated my answer above with the relevant code.

Comment: Sorry, for late response. Wow, thank you very much! you're officially a major contributor to my project! works perfectly!